# Issue installing SQL Server Enterprise Edition 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When i try to install  SQL Server Enterprise edition 2008 I get the following error.

> This program has compatibility issue.You can get help online and see
>   more options..

Suggestions please.

Comment: *i try to install SQL Server Enterprise edition 2008 on VS 2013* Try installing it on Windows.

Comment: Can you not just ignore the message, install the Server and then update the server to solve the issue.

Comment: Ignored and installed it...but how to upgrade now?

Comment: I'm not seeing any changes in VS 2013 WORKING environment (SQL Server Object Explorer or Server EXplorer)...i had re-added the .mdf file but still no improvement.

Comment: I am seeing a VS 2005,2008 in my Documents folder alongwith SQL server Management Studios.

Answer (score 0):

Install the server and then the update (I suggest sp3):

http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=27594

Comment: It works from here. anyway: after you install SQL Server, go on microsoft site, download for free last sql server service pack for your version and install it.